# Display MySQL Data using PHP based on certain dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database called "maintenance" and this has the following columns.

sequence (INT11)
from_date (DATETIME)
to_date (DATETIME)
serviceimpact (LONGTEXT)
servicesaffected (LONGTEXT)
reason (LONGTEXT)

Basically, i add data when service maintenance for servers is going to take place so i want the information to display a few days before the `from_date` and then still display a few days after then `to_date` then after that dissapear and just display a message to say

"No maintenance will be taking place anytime soon"

At the moment i have:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM maintenance where from_date >= date(NOW()) and to_date <= date(NOW()) ORDER BY from_date ASC";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        echo '<strong>Maintenance Period:</strong> '.$result["from_date"].' to '.$result["to_date"].'<br><br>';
        echo '<strong>Services Affected</strong><br>';
        echo nl2br(stripslashes($result["servicesaffected"])).'<br><br>';
        echo '<strong>Service Impact:</strong><br>';
        echo nl2br(stripslashes($result["serviceimpact"])).'<br><br>';
        echo '<strong>Reason for Maintenance:</strong><br>';
        echo nl2br(stripslashes($result["reason"])).'<br><br><hr /><br><br';
    }
}
else
{
    //otherwise, display a message to say everything is running fine
    echo 'There is currently no planned outages for maintenance or upgrade on any of our platforms.';
}
```

but its not working how i want it to - any ideas what i could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM maintenance
WHERE to_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    AND from_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
ORDER BY from_date ASC
```

Note that it should be DAY, not DAYS, in the DATE_SUB/ADD functions.

Comment: i get a syntax error here: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAY) AND from_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 ORDER BY from_date ASC' at line 2

Comment: Yeah, I made an error in my query and I think you managed to copy it during the 15 seconds it took me to correct it. Try again now, please. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_SUB() and DATE_ADD()

`$sql="SELECT * FROM maintenance where from_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND to_date <= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) ORDER BY from_date ASC";`

Comment: this is displaying all the rows in that table? :/

Comment: I put OR instead of AND I've fixed it up also  corrected the DAY interval being DAYS instead